# Constraints passed when creating table as select

Tags: sql, oracle

When I perform a CTaS to populate a new table, which constraints are passed onto the resulting table? Oracle documentation isn't explicit in explaining which constraints are passed.

Comment: Only the ones you specify in the CT part.

Answer (score 2):

> When I perform a CTaS to populate a new table, which constraints are passed onto the resulting table?

Oracle will create `NOT NULL` constraints by default but no others.

However, you can tell it to create constraints (except for foreign key constraints) when you create the table:

For example:

```sql
CREATE TABLE people (
  id   CONSTRAINT people__id__pk PRIMARY KEY,
  name CONSTRAINT people__name__u UNIQUE
       CONSTRAINT people__name__nn NOT NULL,
  dept CONSTRAINT people__dept__chk CHECK ( dept > 0 )
) AS
SELECT 1, 'Alice', 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'Beryl', 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'Carol', 1 FROM DUAL;
```

However, if you try to add in a foreign key constraint:

```sql
CREATE TABLE people (
  id   CONSTRAINT people__id__pk PRIMARY KEY,
  name CONSTRAINT people__name__u UNIQUE
       CONSTRAINT people__name__nn NOT NULL,
  dept CONSTRAINT people__dept__chk CHECK ( dept > 0 ),
  CONSTRAINT people__dept__fk FOREIGN KEY ( dept ) REFERENCES departments ( id )
) AS
SELECT 1, 'Alice', 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'Beryl', 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'Carol', 1 FROM DUAL;
```

This fails with:

> ```
> ORA-02440: Create as select with referential constraints not allowed
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=381903f7c36c75a960a50de67b08b5bc)*